# Given $P(3i) = P(1 − i) = 5$, find $P(2)$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

I'm given that $P(x)$ be a monic 4th degree polynomial with real coefficients and that $P(3i) = P(1 − i) = 5$. I'm supposed to compute P(2), which is 31, but I need to show the work for it.

If $3i$ and $1-i$ were roots, I would know that $-3i$ and $1+i$ were also roots, but I'm not sure how you get there. And I tried $P(3i)-5 = P(1 − i)-5 = 0$ (shifting down 5 units such that $Q(x) = P(x)-5$ and $3i$ and $1-i$ were roots of $Q(x)$ but that didn't seem to go anywhere. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: So, $Q(x)=P(x)-5$ is a $4^{th}$ degree monic polynomial with real coefficients and we know $4$ roots, so we can easily compute $Q(2)$.

Comment: $3i$ is a root of $P(x)-5$. then $\overline{3i}$ is a root of $P(x)-5$. The same with $1-i$

Comment: Another way is to let $P(x) = x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ and directly use the two equalities and form $4$ equations.

Comment: Oh, of course. I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the polynomial has real coeficients $-3i$ and $1+i$ also gives value $5$ so \begin{align}P(x) &= (x-3i)(x+3i)(x-1+i)(x-1-i)+5\\
&= (x^2+9)((x-1)^2+1)+5\\
\end{align}